# Use a SATA3 ssd on a USB3 external case will greatly compromising performance?

Tags: sata, usb-3, sata-to-usb

I have a mac mini late 2014, I do not want to open it not to lose the warranty. so I decided that I will use my ssd it with an external case USB3.

Will there be any difference in performance / very noticeable throughput?

Comment: SATA 3 has a speed of 6 Gbits per second. USB 3 has a speed of 5 Gbit/s.  Both are unlikely to achieve those speeds.  Your SSD has a greater chance of reaching those speeds then a traditional mechanical HDD

Comment: @Ramhound, You mean It is not too bad?

Comment: I provided you the specifications.  You decide if it's bad or not